# TCA Language Selection in TYPO3 7.6

Tags: configuration, typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I created my own CE in TYPO3 6 and I do get the options "Language", "Columns", "Before", ... , and "Index" in my General Tab when I open the CE in the Backend.

But now I updated to TYPO3 7.6 and I do NOT get the listed options. Only when I use the extension "compatibility6" I do see them.

Here is my TCA configuration:

```
// Backend configuration
    $TCA['tt_content']['types'][$pluginSignature]['showitem'] = '
    CType;;4;button;1-1-1, header;' . $locallangXml . ':header,
    --div--;' . $locallangXml . ':tabs.plugin,pi_flexform;' . $locallangXml . ':header.plugin,
    --div--;' . $locallangXml . ':tabs.plugin,pi_flexform_CType;;;;1-1-1,
    --div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xml:pages.tabs.access, starttime, endtime, fe_group, colPos, l18n_parent,l18n_diffsource, backupColPos,
    tx_gridelements_backend_layout,tx_gridelements_children,tx_gridelements_container,tx_gridelements_columns';
```

Finally some screens to show you my problem.

Typo3 7.6 with installed extension "compatibility6"

[With installed extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWYp9.png)

Typo3 7.6 without the extension. Important features are missing! How do I get them back?

[Without the extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEpPy.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are using palettes which have been removed from the core and have been migrated to the extension `compatibility6`. Check out https://github.com/FriendsOfTYPO3/compatibility6/blob/master/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php#L167-L192 for an example.

So instead of using `;;4` you can use `;;general` or you copy the palettes from the compabiltity6 ext to your own own.